# Changing column color with selection of the dropdown in next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make excel sheet where there are 2 columns.
First column contains of text data like questions and second column contain answers like YES/NO in form of drop down with help of list in data validation.

What I want to achieve is that

1) if I select YES in second column then first column should change its color to Green

2) if I select NO in second column then first column should change its color to Red

[image]

is it possible?

Comment: You can do this with conditional formatting, button on the right before format table in your image.

Comment: @SolarMike, Thank you for the suggestion, I tried workaround and was success fully accomplish the task with conditional formatting. I will post answer to the post so that post will be answered and question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For Yes and Green color condition

Selected Cells (For example B1:B11) that I wanted to fill with color > Selected Conditional formatting>Selected New rules> Selected "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" > Inserted formula as `=$C2:$C11="Yes"` in text field for "Format values where this formula is true" > selected "format" option> Selected "fill" option in Newly opened format cells window> Selected Green color and then hit "OK" twice and done.

2) For No and Red color condition (Followed same procedure as above)
Selected Cells (For example B1:B11) that I wanted to fill with color > Selected Conditional formatting>Selected New rules> Selected "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" > Inserted formula as `=$C2:$C11="No"` in text field for "Format values where this formula is true" > selected "format" option> Selected "fill" option in Newly opened format cells window> Selected Red color and then hit "OK" twice and done.

That's all and it worked.

[image: cell color formatting]